# KNN for predict class from new data

Tags: r, knn, text-classification, tf-idf

How do you provide a class for new data that does not have a class?

I use the KNN algorithm and here is the code for modeling. 
(**Text Classification)**

```
train_set <- sample(1:nrow(dtm.df), 15)
test_set <- (1:nrow(dtm.df))[- train_set]

# Isolate classifier
classifier <- dtm.df[, "class"]

# Create model data and remove "category"
model_data <- dtm.df[,!colnames(dtm.df) %in% "class"]

# Create model: training set, test set, training set classifier
knn.pred <- knn(model_data[train_set, ], model_data[test_set, ],
classifier[train_set], k=5)
```

I try this code

```
newdata <- data.frame(text="bagus sekali")
newdata <- Corpus(VectorSource(newdata))
newdata <- DocumentTermMatrix(newdata)
model = knn(model_data[train_set, ], newdata, classifier[train_set], k =5)
```

Error in knn(model_data[train_set, ], newdata, classifier[train_set],  : 
  dims of 'test' and 'train' differ

I know the dims is different, test is 37 288 and newdata is 1 1.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @darnir Edited. Please check.